CDI for RESTEasy Application & Resources doesnt work in Tomcat 10.1.17 with Weld 5.1.2.Final
I'm trying to get CDI to work in RESTEasy resources in Tomcat 10.1.17, but it eludes me.

Deploying to a Tomcat 10.1.17 container using JKube 1.16.2
RESTEasy 6.2.8.Final for Rest services support
Weld 5.1.2 for concrete CDI support
got an empty beans.xml in WEB-INF
got a content.xml file in META-INF that looks like this:

<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager"
              auth="Container"
              type="jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
              factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
</Context>


web.xml file is slim and has these contents:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"
         version="5.0">

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>


Dependencies in pom.xml:

        <!-- RESTEasy stuff -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-cdi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-servlet-initializer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI Implementation: -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Logs output:
[INFO] k8s: 10-May-2024 11:13:41.605 INFO [main] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
[INFO] k8s: 10-May-2024 11:13:41.613 INFO [main] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.<clinit> WELD-000900: 5.1.2 (Final)
[INFO] k8s: 10-May-2024 11:13:41.652 INFO [main] org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory.create WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
[INFO] k8s: 10-May-2024 11:13:41.711 INFO [main] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
[INFO] k8s: 10-May-2024 11:13:41.793 INFO [main] org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.TomcatContainer.initialize WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.

When I implement a listener with "@WebListener" and annotated a field with "@Inject", it works.
However, "@Inject" doesn't work for fields inside Resource class (annotated with "@Path") or for Application class (annotated with "@ApplicationPath").
I did put a dependency for resteasy-cdi in the pom.xml file. According to RESTEasy docs this should be it ?!
What am I missing here to make CDI work in RESTEasy ?

Do you have a beans.xml file in your WAR?

Wrote in details: "got an empty beans.xml in WEB-INF"

If you turn on debug logging you should see some logs form RESTEasy about how the resource was created. If you have some kind of reproducer I could have a look as to what might be happening.

How do I turn on debug logging ?

That depends on the log manager you're using. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/logging.html is the logging documentation for Tomcat. You'd want to enable debug/finer for org.jboss.resteasy.
